# A problem related to C-Vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $p=(0,0), q=(0,1), r=(1,0)$ be  points  of $\mathbb{C}^2$. What is the dimension of the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $\{f(X,Y) \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y] \ | \text{ deg}f \leq 2 \text{ and } f(p)=f(q)=f(r)=0\}$, where by deg$f$, we mean the total degree of the polynomial $f$?

What does $\mathbb{C}$-vector space mean? Can anyone give me a hint for proceeding

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$-vector space means vector space where the underlying field of scalars is the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Can you give me a hint for proceeding?@MatthewLeingang

Comment: What are the methods you know of for finding the dimension of a vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial in two variables of degree $\le 2$ has the form:
$$f(x,y) = Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F$$
You are given that for the polynomials $f$ in your vector space,
$$f(0,0) = 0\\f(0,1) = 0\\f(1,0) = 0$$
That gives you 3 equations in the $6$ unknowns $A, B, C, D, E, F$.

So when you've solved those three equations as far as you can, how many independent unknowns will you have left?